# How to allow users to add sub-server (sub-domain) in Virtualmin

Tags: webmin

How to allow non-root users to create sub-server (sub-domain) and aliases under their /home/ folders after they log-in into webmin?

When I create for example domain domain.tld and user log-in into webmin he is not able to create for example sub.domain.tld sub-server or alias.

Only root can do this.

Comment: This is probably by design as a security measure. Each user likely has to be a real user inn Linux before this can be done. From there, each user will likely have to be assigned to the group that Apache uses to allow site creation and also be a virtualmin admin. You will want to research this further.

Comment: It is real user, User can use SSH for example

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do is rather complicated. Ultimately, to set subdomains to a maindomain a user needs control over that domain. Likely, they need full control.

I would look into wildcard subdomains using htaccess if I were you. It's possible to have your htaccess file in your rootdomain add and/or redirect subdomains. And therefore it's possible to also have code setup that allows your users to add lines to your htaccess file, adding rootdomains through the process.